# Can't autopopulate fields when adding new record - "You can't assign value to this object"

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, vba

I am trying to make a form where I would enter new data. I am trying to make a combobox which would when I press selected record autofill data in form with known data. So I have Owner [Vlasnik] table and I am able to autofill info about owner but I am not able to change ID_VU which is unique key for each owner.

```
 Private Sub cboID_VU2_Change()
Me.[Vlasnik.ID_VU].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(0)
Me.[Naziv tvrtke].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(1)
Me.[Ime korisnika].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(2)
Me.[Prezime korisnika].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(3)
Me.[Adresa korisnika].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(4)
Me.[Telefon].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(5)
Me.Mail.Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(6)
End Sub
```

Control source of comobox is empty and this is rowsource :

```
SELECT Vlasnik.ID_VU, Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], Vlasnik.Telefon, Vlasnik.Mail FROM Vlasnik ORDER BY Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika];
```

When I try to run a code I am getting error on line

```
Me.[Vlasnik.ID_VU].Value = Me.cboID_VU2.Column(0)
```

with message "You can't assign value to this object"

I think problem is that Vlasnik.ID_VU is set as autonumber

[image: This is how the form looks like :]

Comment: The square brackets encompass two identifiers. Should be `Me.[ID_VU]` I think.

Comment: Than I am getting error "Methor or data member not found"

Comment: The `Me.[ID_VU].Value` square bracket notation is shorthand for something like `Me.Fields("ID_VU").Value` (not familiar with access) - have you tried enumerating the fields to see what's available?

Comment: I have field that is called "Vlasnik.ID_VU"

Comment: Not in your SELECT statement. In your query the field is called ID_VU, Vlasnik is the table it's selected from.

Comment: I meant I have textbox which is called "Vlasnik.ID_VU".

Comment: What do you think it's causing an error? How can I solve it?

Comment: How about you rename the textbox to `ID_VU`?

Comment: Yes, I did and wrote your code but I am still getting this error. I think problem is that Vlasnik.ID_VU is set as autonumber.